# Is it possible to load test cases dynamically using pyunit

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

Is it possible to generate test cases dynamically using pyunit?

My test case folder will contain test cases with names like `ad_xxxxx`, `nd_xxxxx`, `pc_xxxxx`.

So is it possible to dynamically load and list any one of the test cases and select tests with pyunit?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/). It is an automatic test manager for python.